Laravel Test Socialite Login
I want to build "login with google" fetaure with laravel and socialite, but when I write testing on that feature, I return false with message
Method Mockery_2_Laravel_Socialite_Contracts_User::user() does not exist on this mock object
This is my test code
public function test_user_can_login_with_google()
    {
        $socialiteUser = Mockery::mock(SocialiteUser::class);
        $socialiteUser->shouldReceive('getId')->andReturn('1');
        $socialiteUser->shouldReceive('getEmail')->andReturn('john.doe@gmail.com');
        $socialiteUser->shouldReceive('getName')->andReturn('John');

        $socialiteFactory = Mockery::mock(SocialiteFactory::class);
        $socialiteFactory->shouldReceive('driver')->with('google')->andReturn($socialiteUser);
        $this->app->instance(SocialiteFactory::class, $socialiteFactory);

        $response = $this->get('/auth/google/callback');

        $response->assertRedirect('/dashboard');
    }

is anaything wrong with my test case?

->driver() does not return a socialite user, it returns a driver, you then call ->user() and you get the user. Check the docs on how it is used and mock it exactly in that order

Let's learn how to mock using Facade's shouldReceive().
This is a typical pattern that we always use in testing.
use Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite;
use Laravel\Socialite\Two\User;

$user = (new User())->map([
    'id' => 1,
    'email' => '',
    'name' => '',
]);

Socialite::shouldReceive('driver->user')->andReturn($user);

$response = $this->get('/auth/google/callback');

shouldReceive can be used with all Laravel Facades.
